# Parsing Custom Elements in ejabberd packet with erlang

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I need to parse a custom element in the message. My Message format is given below. How can I parse these values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message to="XXXX@chat.XYZ.com" id="v0k4h-128" type="chat">
   <body>Hi</body>
   <request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts" />
   <customInfo xmlns="urn:xmpp:customInfo">
      <customElement1>Some Text</customElement1>
      <customElement2 />
      <customElement3 />
      <customElement4>Some Text</customElement4>
   </customInfo>
</message>
```

Comment: This is invalid XML 1.0. See '"34 The element type "customElement1" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</customElement1>".'

Comment: It was typing mistake I have corrected here

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [`xmerl`](https://erlang.org/doc/apps/xmerl/xmerl_ug.html). Save your xml to a file called `t.xml`.[1](https://erlang.org/doc/apps/xmerl/xmerl_ug.html)

```
1> {ParsResult,Misc}=xmerl_scan:file("t.xml").
{{xmlElement,message,message,[],
             {xmlNamespace,[],[]},
             [],1,
             [{xmlAttribute,to,[],[],[],
                            [{message,1}],
                            1,[],"XXXX@chat.XYZ.com",false},
              {xmlAttribute,id,[],[],[],
                            [{message,1}],
                            2,[],"v0k4h-128",false},
              {xmlAttribute,type,[],[],[],
                            [{message,1}],
                            3,[],"chat",false}],
             [{xmlText,[{message,1}],1,[],"\n   ",text},
              {xmlElement,body,body,[],
                          {xmlNamespace,[],[]},
                          [{message,1}],
                          2,[],
                          [{xmlText,[{body,2},{message,1}],1,[],"Hi",text}],
                          [],".",undeclared},
              {xmlText,[{message,1}],3,[],"\n   ",text},
              {xmlElement,request,request,[],
                          {xmlNamespace,'urn:xmpp:receipts',[]},
                          [{message,1}],
                          4,
                          [{xmlAttribute,xmlns,[],[],[],[...],...}],
                          [],[],".",undeclared},
              {xmlText,[{message,1}],5,[],"\n   ",text},
              {xmlElement,customInfo,customInfo,[],
                          {xmlNamespace,'urn:xmpp:customInfo',[]},
                          [{message,1}],
                          6,
                          [{xmlAttribute,xmlns,[],[],...}],
                          [{xmlText,[{...}|...],1,...},
                           {xmlElement,customElement1,...},
                           {xmlText,...},
                           {...}|...],
                          [],".",undeclared},
              {xmlText,[{message,1}],7,[],"\n",text}],
             [],".",undeclared},
 []}
2>
```

[1](https://erlang.org/doc/apps/xmerl/xmerl_ug.html)

Comment: Can you please provide more help, guide on this